# VertexDelete not working on graph with VertexWeight

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3**

---

Good afternoon,

I have observed an "unexpected behaviour" with VertexDelete and a graph with vertex weights. This is a minimal working example:

**OK**

```
gr = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
            4 \[DirectedEdge] 5}]
FullForm@gr
new = VertexDelete[gr, 5]
FullForm@new
```

`VertexDelete` works as expected. The `FullForm` of `new` is:

```
Graph[List[1, 2, 3, 4], List[DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[1, 3], DirectedEdge[2, 4]]]
```

---

If I assign a vertex weight to vertex 4, I get an error message:

**NOT OK**

```
gr = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
            4 \[DirectedEdge] 5}];
gr = SetProperty[{gr, 4}, VertexWeight -> 666]
FullForm@gr
new = VertexDelete[gr, 5]
FullForm@new

Drop::drop: "Cannot drop positions 5 through 5 in {1,1,1,666}."
```

`FullForm` of `new` contains `$$Failure`:

```
Graph[List[1, 2, 3, 4], List[DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[1, 3], DirectedEdge[2, 4]], 
      List[Rule[VertexWeight, Removed["$$Failure"] ] ] ]
```

I am using *Mathematica* version 10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015).

**I can successfully delete a vertex prior to index 4 (the one where I have assigned a weight to).** I saw some other posts regarding issues with `VertexDelete`. My real graph contains 60k vertices and more than 100k edges.

Can someone confirm this on other OS and version?

Comment: I can confirm the problem on OS X 10.10.3, Mma 10.1.0.  There was a similar problem with EdgeWeight in 10.0, which got fixed.

Comment: Please report this to Wolfram.

Comment: I have reported it a few minutes ago.

Comment: I've experienced similar issues deleting/adding vertices to `Graph` with properties back in v9. Note that `PropertyValue` does not fix this issue either. Fundamentally there is not a `GraphData` object living within `Graph`, allowing you to create objects that cannot be used consistently with the `Graph` functions. If possible I always give my properties first, `Graph[{Property[1,VertexLabels->"foo"],2,3},{Property[1->2,EdgeWeight->4],2->3,3->1}]` but even that won't save you here :(